# Create view having nested json text from a table - Postgres

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, sql-view

Say, I have the following postgres table,

```sql
> select * from t;
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
| id | a       | b         | c       | d       |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1  | value_a | value_b   | value_c | value_d |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
...
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
|... | ...     | ...       | ...     | ...     |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Now I want to create a view from this table which is capable of storing data of following format having nested json text.

And this should be grouped by `id` column.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "a": "A",
  "x":"{\"k1\":\"value_b\",\"k2\":\"{\"k21\":\"value_c\",\"k22\":\"value_d\"}\"}"
}
```

I have no idea how can I achieve this. Anyone there to write me a postgres sql query for this.

Comment: Do you expect one row in the view for each row in the source table, or there is some aggregation involved (in which case you would need to show more than one row of data)?

Comment: @GMB You can assume one row in the view for each row in the source table for now.

Comment: @GMB What if I my nested json field is an array from another table which I have to get by a query? I have updated the question, please provide a suggestion/answer. And also keep your original answer. That was also a part of my question.

Comment: It is not a good practice to substiantially update a question after answers were posted. I would suggest accepting the answer (if you believe that it properly responded your *original* question) and asking *a new question*, providing proper new sample data and expected results.

Comment: @GMB Yeah that makes sense. Btw, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `json(b)_build_*` functions to generate json(b):

```
create view myview as
select 
    id,
    a,
    jsonb_build_object(
        'k1', b,
        'k2', jsonb_build_object(
            'k21', c,
            'k22', d
        )
    ) as x
from mytable
```

If you want the whole row as a single json object:

```
create view myview as
select jsonb_build_object(
    'id', id
    'a', a,
     'x', jsonb_build_object(
        'k1', b,
        'k2', jsonb_build_object(
            'k21', c,
            'k22', d
        )
    )
) val
from mytable
```